# BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress breaks out of method

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker

It seems like wherever I call ReportProgress on my BackgroundWorker, the processing of that method stops so my work never finishes. Example:

```
int numQuals = this.Model.Names.Count();
int currentQual = 0;
int fivePercent = (int)(numQuals * .05);
foreach (var qualName in this.Model.Names)
{
    if ((worker != null) && ((currentQual % fivePercent == 0)))
    {
        worker.ReportProgress((int) (((float)++currentQual / numQuals) * 100));
    }

    // This next line never processes. I can debug and it will 
    // break at the ReportProgress line but won't ever break here
    this.myContainer.Add(...
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox.  And add code to do something with e.Error in your RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: What you have posted tells us nothing.  How about posting the code for ReportProgress

Comment: @Ramhound: He can't. [`BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) is part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: All `ReportProgress` does is raise the `ProgressChanged` event. If that's blocking then his event handler is blocking. We need to see his event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set `worker.WorkerReportsProgress=true` ? Otherwise, the background worker will terminate with an exception and the work will not be fullfilled.

Comment: @KrisTrip: Then you have to check with the debuger. Be aware that if you have in the ReportProgress-event any faulty code, this will break the execution of the background worker. THis means that the error is either in the line where you call ReportProgress (division by zero or something like this) or the error is in the ReportProgress eventhandler.

Comment: Yup, turns out a had a silly error in the eventhandler causing an exception. This is why I shouldn't be lazy and always make sure I check e.Error as @Hans Passant said.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separating out your calculating logic to a different line.  I hate seeing inline stuff like this from other developers.  It's harder to read and harder to debug (as your question points out).

Your worker should never be null if you are inside the do work method.  Although I do recommend performing null checks - if a null existed here something else is majorly wrong.

```
 if ((worker != null) && ((currentQual % fivePercent == 0)))
 {
        object result =  ((float)++currentQual / (float)numQuals) * 100;
        int resultint = 0;
        if(Int32.TryParse(result.ToString(), out resultint))
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(Convert.ToInt32(result));
        }
 }
```